# get_template_names(self) doesn't work in TemplateView

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use `PDFView` from `django-pdfkit`. The problem is that I don't have one template. Instead I have 4 templates. The template chosen depends on request.GET parameter.

So I've created a `View` called Test which extends `PDFView`.

```
class Test(PDFView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        # don't bother with chosing template for now
        return ["pdf/dobropis_pdf_template.html"]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        doklad = get_object_or_404(Doklad, pk=self.request.GET.get('id'))
        return {'doklad':doklad}
```

The problem is that if I don't specify `template_name`, It returns:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /render/doklad/ None

So I suppose the `get_template_names` method isn't even called.

Why is that so? How can I make it work?

This is from `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^render/doklad/', views.Test.as_view(), name="doklad_to_pdf"),
```

This is a `PDFView` (in case it helps):

```
class PDFView(TemplateView):
    #: Set to change the filename of the PDF.
    filename = None

    #: Set to default the PDF display to inline.
    inline = False

    #: Set pdfkit options dict.
    pdfkit_options = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return a HTTPResponse either of a PDF file or HTML.

        :rtype: HttpResponse
        """
        if 'html' in request.GET:
            # Output HTML
            content = self.render_html(*args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponse(content)

        else:
            # Output PDF
            content = self.render_pdf(*args, **kwargs)

            response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')

            if (not self.inline or 'download' in request.GET) and 'inline' not in request.GET:
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % self.get_filename()

            response['Content-Length'] = len(content)

            return response

    def render_pdf(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Render the PDF and returns as bytes.

        :rtype: bytes
        """
        html = self.render_html(*args, **kwargs)

        options = self.get_pdfkit_options()
        if 'debug' in self.request.GET and settings.DEBUG:
            options['debug-javascript'] = 1

        kwargs = {}
        wkhtmltopdf_bin = os.environ.get('WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN')
        if wkhtmltopdf_bin:
            kwargs['configuration'] = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkhtmltopdf_bin)

        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options, **kwargs)

        return pdf

    def get_pdfkit_options(self):
        """
        Returns ``self.pdfkit_options`` if set otherwise a default dict of options to supply to pdfkit.

        :rtype: dict
        """
        if self.pdfkit_options is not None:
            return self.pdfkit_options

        return {
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
        }

    def get_filename(self):
        """
        Return ``self.filename`` if set otherwise return the template basename with a ``.pdf`` extension.

        :rtype: str
        """
        if self.filename is None:
            name = splitext(basename(self.template_name))[0]
            return '{}.pdf'.format(name)

        return self.filename

    def render_html(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Renders the template.

        :rtype: str
        """
        static_url = '%s://%s%s' % (self.request.scheme, self.request.get_host(), settings.STATIC_URL)
        media_url = '%s://%s%s' % (self.request.scheme, self.request.get_host(), settings.MEDIA_URL)

        with override_settings(STATIC_URL=static_url, MEDIA_URL=media_url):
            template = loader.get_template(self.template_name)
            context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            html = template.render(context)
            return html
```

Comment: attach the template name as a parameter within the URL?

Comment: How can this help? I can choose template by checking request. There is a problem that get_template_names just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By overriding `get`, you've bypassed *all* the built-in functionality for that view, including the calling of `get_template_names`. This is very rarely the right thing to do.

However, given the code you've shown, what's the reason why you can't call that method yourself from `render_html`? Or just inline the logic there.

Comment: I use function based views almost only so that's why I didn't want extending the PDFView. Finally I've override get and it works. Thanks